# I am building a real time collaboration tool where user can keep multiple conversation at the same time

Tags: xmpp

So I needed some kind of thread handling for this requirement. I went through XEP-0201 and found it useful, but I am not able to find any XMPP server and client that implemented XEP-0201.

Please let me know if anybody has used/wrote the XEP-0201 or if there is some other mechanism in XMPP so that I can handle multiple threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't find servers that support [XEP-0201](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0201.html) - it's purely a client thing. Clients add the `<thread>` element to messages, and the recipient will receive it. The XEP is about general best practices around how to use that mechanism.

Comment: I got your point. Is there any existing XMPP client library that supports this XEP?

Comment: Sure, plenty. You don't mention what language though. Smack, Swiften, SleekXMPP all do as far as I know - and many of the others allow direct stanza to achieve the same thing anyway.

Comment: Pretty sure Spark supports it as well since it was written with Smack.